# Kubernetes error: unknown field "otel" error when trying to setup Open Telemetry with Dapr

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, open-telemetry, dapr

I'm following the Dapr documentation to have Dapr sending data to an Open Telemetry collector pod in kubernetes.
The first step is to configure Dapr to send distributed tracing data.
[Tracing Docs](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/monitoring/tracing/setup-tracing/)

So I'm trying to add the following yaml file to kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: tracing
spec:
  tracing:
    samplingRate: "1"
    otel:
      endpointAddress: "localhost:4317"
      isSecure: false
      protocol: grpc
```

Using the command: `kubectl apply -f .\tracing-config.yaml`

Problem is that I'm getting the following error:

> error: error validating ".\zeta\components\tracing-config.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Configuration.spec.tracing): unknown field "otel" in io.dapr.v1alpha1.Configuration.spec.tracing; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Even if I try to use `kubectl apply -f .\tracing-config.yaml --validate=false`, what happens is that the field "otel" and it's subfields are ignored when applied.

Since that yaml exists in Dapr's official documentation, I imagine this should be doable. Is there a way to add a field even if it is not recognized? Or some other workaround for this?

Comment: Are you using Dapr version `v1.10`? The `tracing` field didn't exist prior to this version.

Answer (score 1):

As Juliano Costa mentioned, in fact, I had the dapr sidecars updated, but not dapr it self and the version I was using did not support the "otel" field. Updating it to the version 1.10 fixed it.